# mapping row to column names in sql

Tags: sql-server

i have two tables Table A and Table B

A.

```
channelname  variablename
------------------------------
TCO1           INPUT CHANNEL  
TC02           OUTPUT CHANNEL
TCO3           TEST CHANNEL
```

B.

```
TC01    TC02   TC03
--------------------
100     443    322
200     566    990
376     453    342
45      422    856
```

I want the output of table B as :

```
inputchannel   outputchannel   testchannel
--------------------------------------------- 
100            443             322
200            566             990
376            453             342
45             422             856
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand your problem if you do not format your tables

Comment: i formatted it in the text box but when i post it the formatting is ruined.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL? or other SQL?

Comment: does it need to be done dynamically or can you just sp_rename? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx

Comment: it has to be done dynamically...

Comment: How many columns can be at the table `B`? Do you want to rename columns or crete query?

Comment: the columns in table B can go upto 150.

Comment: i want to create a single query to rename all the columns.

Comment: So tableA has the new column names? It is not totally clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: in table A ...channelname is the channelnumber and variablename is its meaning. So i want the channelname to be replaced by its meaning in table B

Comment: Ahh so not renaming columns, dynamic sql to pull column names. Yuck. That is a painful design but it can be dealt with. I have to run but if nobody provides an answer I will check again in the morning.

Comment: Sure...any help would be appreciated..Thanks once again

Comment: This question was asked in google interview yesterday and i could not answer. i am sure there is some genius out there who can answer this question for me...

Comment: It can be done with a clean solution if the column names aren't dynamic. Are you sure it won't be sufficient?

Comment: You can use a cursor, although Google probably wouldn't like that

Comment: @mzedeler lets assume the column names are not dynamic...If you could still provide a solution that would be awesome...

Comment: That's possible using plain sql if you have a fairly recent ms sql server. I'll post the solution tomorrow if nobody does it before me...

Comment: Good luck with the interview. I am certainly not going to write code for your interview.

Answer (score 0):

Need to use cursor if you do not want to change column name:
something like:

```
    Declare @sSQL as varchar(400) -- You can alway make it larger
    Declare @channelname  as varchar(50) -- You can alway make it larger
    Declare @variablename  as varchar(50) -- You can alway make it larger
    Set @sSQL=''
    DECLARE col_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    select c.name, a.variablename from 
    sys.columns c 
    inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id 
    inner join [A] as a on a.channelname = c.name 
    where t.name = 'B'
    OPEN col_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor 
    INTO @channelname, @variablename
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        If @sSQL=''
        BEGIN
            Set @sSQL='select [' + @channelname + ']as[' + @variablename + '] '
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            Set @sSQL= @sSQL + ',[' + @channelname + ']as[' + @variablename + '] '
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM col_cursor 
        INTO @channelname, @variablename
    END 
    CLOSE col_cursor
    DEALLOCATE col_cursor
    Set @sSQL= @sSQL + ' from [B]'
    Exec(@sSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

because people don't like cursors:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max) = N'create table ##temp ('
select @var = @var + variablename + ' varchar(max),' from TableA
set @var = LEFT(@var, LEN(@var) - 1) + ')'

execute sp_executesql @var

insert into ##temp
select * from TableB

select * into TableNew from ##temp
drop table TableB
```

**EDIT** of course test this before you drop any tables.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comment:

> i want to create a single query to rename all the columns. –  Orson
>   DCunha

Please try something like this:

```
declare @columnNameFrom nvarchar(100), @columnNameTo nvarchar(100)
declare @tablename nvarchar(100)

SET @tablename  = 'B'

DECLARE rename_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    select @tablename + '.' + c.name
    ,      A.variablename
    from   syscolumns c 
           inner join sysobjects o on o.id = c.id
           inner join A on A.channelname = c.name
     where  o.name = @tablename  

OPEN rename_cursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM rename_cursor 
INTO @columnNameFrom, @columnNameTo
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SET @columnNameTo = REPLACE(@columnNameTo, ' ', '')
  EXEC sp_executesql N'exec sp_rename @NameFrom, @NameTo'
  , N'@NameFrom nvarchar(100), @NameTo nvarchar(100)'
  , @columnNameFrom, @columnNameTo;

  FETCH NEXT FROM rename_cursor  
  INTO @columnNameFrom, @columnNameTo
END 
CLOSE rename_cursor 
DEALLOCATE rename_cursor ;
```